# div-css table with height: 100%, div-rows not resizing in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, tablelayout

I want to make layout that take 100% of the screen height (min) with header, body and footer ... the body and the footer will have hard-coded height and the body will be elastic to resize accordingly ... if empty or less content will take the rest height space, if full of content will stretch and be bigger, pushing down the footer div.

It works great but not in IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/swkrt/

```
<div class="content-holder">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.content-holder {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.content-holder div {
    display: table-row;
}

.header {
    height: 50px;
}

.footer {
    height: 100px;
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Silly question, but you are using a reset sheet, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find solution for this issue so i go and use  ... it works fine in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<div class="content-holder">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Add :

```
**.content-holder {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.body{
  height: 76.8%;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var DocHeight = $(document).height()-150;
 $('.content-holder').css('height',DocHeight+'px');
});
```

Comment: remove height:100% from css
if you want to set height according to screen then use $(window).height() rather then $(document).height()

Comment: Do you want to have header and footer with fixed height?

Comment: Well I think you have to manage your header's and footer's height also in percentage as well as of body div for IE 7 If there is any issue regarding of using JS.

Comment: Percentage for header and footer height does not work for me. The layout must hold header and footer's height and make the body resizable. 2 Cases to test if you are not sure: 1. Empty body ... footer must be at the bottom. 2. Body must be full of content, so much content so scroller is needed. It the second case ... the windows must have global scroller, body be as long as content need it to be and footer holds its height and be at the end of the scrolled page.    If this thing is done with table with tr td's it works!